# Group under multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is this a group from the positive reals to the positive reals under multiplication? **Is there anything interesting about it?** What are some things you could study about it? Here is the group of **functions** in question:

$$ \left\lbrace \zeta(s)^{\large\frac{1}{\log x}} : s \in \Bbb R>1 \right\rbrace, $$

The group operation is multiplication, the identity element is $1$, inverse elements are
$$ \left\lbrace \zeta(s)^{\large\frac{-1}{\log x}} : s \in \Bbb R>1 \right\rbrace, $$
the domain is not equal to $1$ or $0$, and the codomain is not equal to $1$ or $0$.
Is $ \frac{1}{\log x} $ extraneous?
It's Abelian because the multiplication of any elements is commutative right?

$$ \zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}. $$

Below is a picture of what the group roughly resembles in terms of some of it's functions. You can see from the representation of the group below that the non-inverse elements are involutions. They are symmetric about the line $y=x$.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: What is $s_k$???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your group is isomorphic to $(\Bbb R_{> 0}, \times)$ (by associating $\zeta(s) \in \Bbb R_{> 0}$ to each of your functions), and also to $(\Bbb R,+)$ by going one step further and considering $\log(\zeta(s))$.

As a group, there is no point in obfuscating it by indexing it with $s$ instead of $t = \log(\zeta(s))$ and there is also no point in obfuscating it by viewing its elements as functions of $x$ or of $\log x$.

That each element is an involution (under composition) is irrelevant to the study of your group since it's equipped with multiplication and not composition, and so it is irrelevant to your question as stated. This suggests this is maybe not quite the question you wanted to ask and so I'm afraid that noone knows what you truely want.

The appearance of $\zeta$ is completely unmotivated you could rewrite your question for the better by replacing $\zeta(s)$ with $t$ without changing anything, or for worse by replacing it with any other complicated bijective expression of your choosing. I don't know about the others but I am wondering why did you write $\zeta(s)$ instead of the much much cooler $\zeta(1+\zeta(1+\zeta(s)))))$